# Apache with PHP-FPM intercepting errors and not displaying my friendly PHP error page output in dev environment

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, 503-error, error-handling

There is so much static around this it's hard to find an answer that actually applies, so my apologies if there is an answer for this, I just haven't been able to find it.

My situation is that I want to display errors from our application on the page when they happen... **in our DEVELOPMENT environment**.... I don't need to be told to only send them to the logs, it's a giant waste of time during dev and not near as formatted to have to read them out of the logs.  **We of course turn this off in production.**

My errors ARE being logged, this is not the problem, the issue is, they are not being DISPLAYED before Apache redirects them with a 503 response code, most likely because of PHP/FPM dying with a fatal error that we didn't catch properly.

Prior to moving to PHP-FPM, any kind of error was displayed no problem, we have the standard settings in place in `/etc/php.ini`...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
error_display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

And my exception/error handler was working great, I could access my stack trace details, extra meta, etc., however now that I've got PHP-FPM enabled, Apache seems to be capturing the returning http 503 status, and is redirecting to the generic apache error message.  I've tried using...

```
errordocument 503 /error.php?...
```

... but this loses state so I don't get all the details I would normally have gotten in the `shutdown` handler I normally use.  I've added the following to the FPM pool definition...

```
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = On
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = On
```

... but they had no effect.  `php_info()` is showing both master and local values are working as expected, so it's not a misconfiguration, or errant include file somewhere.

What am I doing wrong, how can I stop apache from forwarding to it's own error handler and just display the output of PHP-FPM, and by extension my own error handler?

```
Apache:  2.4.37-21
PHP/FPM: 7.3.5-5
```

Comment: 503 is semantically the wrong response for this anyway; you should be responding with 500 in this scenario. See RFC 7231 section 6.6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton true enough, depends a bit on where the error was coming from and how the exception/error was captured because I don't think we're returning the 503 specifically (I'll update my question accordingly), but I do agree, we still have some work to do to make up for past mistakes ;)  I have a feeling, it might be defaulting to a 503 in Apache because PHP/FPM is dying with a fatal error, which is part of the issue, it's just a blanket override basically.

Comment: And you're right about all the junk on the Internet when you try to search for something like this. But I read a bunch of stuff and got the vague impression that Apache handles 503 specially. I haven't done a whole lot with Apache since switching most everything to nginx in 2008, so I probably can't be much more help (unless you want to switch to nginx)...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Some days I get that urge :D  Thanks for your insights, I'll see what I can dig up on the 503 handling specifically, hopefully it'll lead to something.

Comment: I don't regret it for a moment. I'm quite glad to have mostly left Apache behind.